# Riley is back in Class

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> My Prefix is a pet
>   My suffix violent,
>   My Infix thinks himself 
>   to be most important

**What Am I?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you:

> CATEGORY

My Prefix is a pet

> CAT

My suffix violent

> GORY

My Infix thinks himself to be most important

> EGO

And the title: *Riley is back in Class*

> "Class" is a synonym of "category".

Comment: awesome, you got it.. i will accept the answer tomorrow .

Answer (score 2):

This may be a partial answer:

Why not

> CATION

Prefix is a pet

> CAT

suffix violent

> ION (an atom or molecule with a net electric charge due to the loss or gain of one or more electrons)

My Infix thinks himself

> I

to be most important

> CATION means a positively charged ion, i.e., one that would be attracted to the cathode in electrolysis

and Title: 'Riley is back in Class'

> Chemistry Class -> reading about Ionic compounds

Comment: the suffix part is a bit of a stretch, and the 'to be most important part' is about the infix, not whole word, but nevertheless a nice answer $(+1)$ for you